# How to modify the default RoR behavior to AJAX CRUD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want a table to do CRUD, but I want it in an Ajax way, how can I modify the default RoR behavior, any suggestions on that?

I tried comment these code in destroy method, but it don't work, it saw missing the destroy.erb:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(categories_url) }

  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will default to HTML if you don't give (and accept) a different response. Check out [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs) to see how to set up an AJAX request and response with RJS (there's another on how to do it with jQuery).

Basically you'll need a format.js line. You can also make a view of the form .js.erb where you write JavaScript to run on the server response.

As a side note though, unless you have a very specific website, I'd suggest not doing *only* AJAX. It's not very accessible for users without JavaScript, like blind users with a screenreader.

Comment: It also annoys us lazy bastards, er... power users who navigate via keyboard because we can't be bothered to reach for the mouse.